# OnclientClick executes and then Page is Postback

Tags: javascript

I am working with the RadButton inside the User Control...

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="tbnCancel"
                   runat="server"
                   Text="Cancel"
                   OnClientClicked="CloseEditFormTodoList" >
</telerik:RadButton>
```

And I am Calling javascript Function for Closing User Control

```
function CloseEditFormTodoList(sender, eventArgs) {

    var masterTable = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
    masterTable.cancelAll();
    return false;
}
```

My User Control is Close But the Page is postback.

How to avoid Postback?

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe on `OnClientClicking` event instead of the `OnClientClicked` and call set_Cancel method of args parameter:

```
function CloseEditFormTodoList(sender, eventArgs) {

    var masterTable = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
    masterTable.cancelAll();
    eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
}
```

Check this documentation: [OnClientClicking](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-onclientclicking.html)